# How to save a xaml grid as a pdf?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a xaml grid that has a few textblocks, images and polylines that are updated by a user input. Is there anyway to output this grid as a pdf? I have a similar thing set up in Excel with VBA where a userform is filled in which edits a sheets and saves that page as a pdf but was looking for something similar in what I'm working on now.

Is there some documentation someone could me towards?

Comment: Does the following answer works, And do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to save a xaml grid as a pdf?

UWP platform provide [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager?view=winrt-19041) api that could convert xaml page to pdf document. Please refer [Print from your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) document. And here is official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).